# php not picking up variables from html form

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I'm new to PHP so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

```
<?php

$date = $_POST['date'];
$promoter = $_POST['promoter'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$headliner = $_POST['headliner'];
$headsite = $_POST['headsite'];
$headdesc = $_POST['headdesc'];
$support1 = $_POST['support1'];
$sup1site = $_POST['sup1site'];
$sup1desc = $_POST['sup1desc'];
$support2 = $_POST['support2'];
$sup2site = $_POST['sup2site'];
$sup2desc = $_POST['sup2desc'];
$support3 = $_POST['support3'];
$sup3site = $_POST['sup3site'];
$sup3desc = $_POST['sup3desc'];
$support4 = $_POST['support4'];
$sup4site = $_POST['sup4site'];
$sup4desc = $_POST['sup4desc'];
$support5 = $_POST['support5'];
$sup5site = $_POST['sup5site'];
$sup5desc = $_POST['sup5desc'];

print '<b>$date</b> - info: <a href="mailto:$email">$promoter</a><br />';
print '<b>$headliner</b> [<a href="$headsite" target="_blank">$headsite</a>]<br />';
print '<i>$headdesc</i><br />';
print '<b>$support1</b> [<a href="$sup1site" target="_blank">$sup1site</a>]<br />';
print '<i>$sup1desc</i><br />';
print '<b>$support2</b> [<a href="$sup2site" target="_blank">$sup2site</a>]<br />';
print '<i>$sup2desc</i><br />';
print '<b>$support3</b> [<a href="$sup3site" target="_blank">$sup3site</a>]<br />';
print '<i>$sup3desc</i><br />';
print '<b>$support4</b> [<a href="$sup4site" target="_blank">$sup4site</a>]<br />';
print '<i>$sup4desc</i><br />';
print '<b>$support5</b> [<a href="$sup5site" target="_blank">$sup5site</a>]<br />';
print '<i>$sup5desc</i><br />';

?>
```

This is my result upon submission...

```
$date - info: $promoter<br />
$headliner [$headsite]<br />
$headdesc<br />
$support1 [$sup1site]<br />
$sup1desc<br />
$support2 [$sup2site]<br />
$sup2desc<br />
$support3 [$sup3site]<br />
$sup3desc<br />
$support4 [$sup4site]<br />
$sup4desc<br />
$support5 [$sup5site]<br />
$sup5desc
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Start your learning adventures here (especially the part about Dealing with Forms) http://php.net/tut.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use double quoted(`"`) strings for variables in them to be expanded. E.g.

```
print "<b>$date</b> - info: <a href=\"mailto:$email\">$promoter</a><br />";
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Great thanks. I was under the impression you couldn't use the same quotations within the string and had to mix ' and ". When is that applicable?

Comment: @user1863781 you just have to escape them e.g. `$doubleQuote = "\"";` or `$singleQuote = '\'';`

Comment: @user1863781 you should accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can write like this

```
print '<b>'.$date.'</b> - info: <a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$promoter.'</a><br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
          echo '<b>'.$date.'</b> - info: <a href="mailto:'. $email.'">'. $promoter .'</a><br />';
  print '<b>'.$headliner.'</b> <a href="'. $headsite.'" target="_blank">'. $headsite.'</a><br />';
  print '<i>'.$headdesc.'</i><br />';
  print '<b>'.$support1.'</b> <a href="'.$sup1site.'" target="_blank">'.$sup1site.'</a><br />';
  print '<i>'.$sup1desc.'</i><br />';
  print '<b>'.$support2.'</b> <a href="'.$sup2site.'" target="_blank">'.$sup2site.'</a><br />';
  print '<i>'.$sup2desc.'</i><br />';
  print '<b>'.$support3.'</b> <a href="'.$sup3site.'" target="_blank">'.$sup3site.'</a><br />';
  print '<i>'.$sup3desc.'</i><br />';
  print '<b>'.$support4.'</b> <a href="'.$sup4site.'" target="_blank">'.$sup4site.'</a><br />';
  print '<i>'.$sup4desc.'</i><br />';
  print '<b>'.$support5.'</b> <a href="'.$sup5site.'" target="_blank">'.$sup5site.'</a><br />';
  print '<i>'.$sup5desc.'</i><br />';
```